# How do I manage puppet nodes with different module versions?

Tags: puppet

I have a setup where we would like to have puppet manage installation and configuration of our software across several servers, but be able to install different versions of the software on different servers.

For example, I want to be able to create a puppet module that contains the server config, dependencies, etc for our version 1.0 and a separate one for version 1.1. From a single puppet master install, I would like to be able to configure some nodes to run version 1.0 and other nodes to run 1.1.

I see that modules allow meta data including a version, but it looks like you can have just one version of a module installed on a puppet master at a time.

Ideally it would be group based, where we can define an "early adopter" group and a "normal" group and as we come up with new versions we can set the early adopter group to use the new version and the normal group to use next oldest.

What is the best way to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways my favourites are the following three:

- For our migration from apache1 to apache2 we created completely separate modules. You'd think this caused a lot of duplication, but we redid our config at the same time.
- For simple upgrades of single packages, we do things like

  ```
  package{"foo":
      ensure => $wants_foo_upgrade ? {
          true => latest,
          false => 1.0
      }
  }
  ```

  where `$wants_foo_upgrade` is based on our infrastructure database, extlookup data or facts
- For things in the middle, we take the second approach and use that variable in determining which configfiles to use, or in templates for configfiles.

Comment: Besides just making sure the correct version of our application is installed as part of a 1.0 or 1.1 release, we would have other puppet changes as well like ensuring newly required directories are installed, dependent packages are updated, etc.

Are you able to do a similar strategy to say "use this version of class our_software"?

Comment: @NathanVoxland You can't have overlapping module names, but if you want to do separate modules, then you probably want the version number in the name - `software_1_0` and `software_1_1` or something.  For the groups, I'd recommend using hiera, but a node inheritance setup would work too.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I'll look into hiera, thanks for the pointer. I was concerned that the "version in the name" approach is what would be needed to support multiple versions of the same module but was hoping there was a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing this by having a single module that takes a version number as a parameter, something like this:

```
class our_software ($version) {
  ...
}
```

What you do within that class depends on how much the two versions of your software have in common.  You might be able to have all of the config files included directly in the class with templates that pick the right values for their settings based on the version number or you might have two separate classes that set up each version's environment entirely differently, with the main class deciding which to include based on the version number.

If you're using hiera (or some other external lookup thing), this lets you specify the desired software version completely separately from the code that says "install our software".

If you want to get fancy, the module could include a fact to indicate what version of the software is currently installed so your module can prohibit things like version downgrades (assuming that's an appropriate thing in your environment).